# Htaccess subdomain exceptions to rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I host in siteground, on a multiple domain account,

Main domain is pointed to public_html, so it's a bit dangerous for the rest of sites in the account to use it (unwanted deletes, hacks, and so...)

I successfully followed this guide (http://www.ianholden.com/how-to/hide-joomla-subdirectory/) to point mydomain.com to midomain.com/mydomain folder (joomla install)

But now I have a problem with existing subdomains for sites still without their own domain names, that give a 500 error when visited...

What could I use to leep my current rewrite rule mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/mydomain and make exceptions for subdomains as whatever.mydomain.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rule that you have added to your .htaccess file will affect all other sites on your hosting account, since the .htaccess file is at the same level of all those sub-directories.

If you have too many sites hosted this way, then I suggest you go with a VPS, and then create an account for each and every domain that you have. This will ensure that your websites run smoothly and in silos.

Whatever you do to make Joomla work properly under a subdomain, will create problems for you on the long run.

Comment: Yes, but a VPS is too much for what I use it, I run several personal projects without traffic, and some business sites really simple... :/